# Stop a common template from being reloaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angularjs-routing, angular-ui-router

I have an Angular application that depends on Angular ui-router. This application has multiple pages which share a common template such as the navbar:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize', 'ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'ui.router'])
    .config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) => {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/index");

        $stateProvider
            .state('index', {
                url: "/index",
                views: {
                    'navbar': {
                        templateUrl: 'Views/Partials/navbar.cshtml',
                        controller: 'App.Controllers.NavbarController'
                    },
                    'content': {
                        templateUrl: 'Views/index.cshtml',
                        controller: 'App.Controllers.IndexController'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('settings', {
                url: "/settings",
                views: {
                    'navbar': {
                        templateUrl: 'Views/Partials/navbar.cshtml',
                        controller: 'App.Controllers.NavbarController'
                    },
                    'content': {
                        templateUrl: 'Views/settings.cshtml',
                        controller: 'App.Controllers.SettingsController'
                    }
                }
            });
    }]);
```

Both `'/index'` and `'/settings'` share the same template `'Views/Partials/navbar.cshtml'`. Upon testing, i found out, that every time a "page" is loaded for an url, all the views in it are reloaded.

**Is it possible to avoid reloading the navbar, if it has been previously loaded already?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to extract the navbar into a parent state of your existing states. This way the navbar only loads when the parent state is entered and you should be able to change child states that share this parent without affecting it.

While there are better organised ways to do this, my quick and dirty way would be to rename the states you have to **withnav.index** and **withnav.settings**. Then remove the navbar view from them and add the following state.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('withnav', {
        abstract: true,
        views: {
            'navbar': {
                templateUrl: 'Views/Partials/navbar.cshtml',
                controller: 'App.Controllers.NavbarController'
            }
        }
    });
```